# Taking the limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, optimization

Hi I am trying to do a question on rate of convergence

I have come across the definition

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|x_{n+1} - r|}{|x_n - r|} $$

My sequende below is as folllows:-

$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{6^n-4}$$

Therefore from the given expression i know i need to obtain $a_{n+1}$
where

$$a_{n+1} = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{6^{n+1}-4}$$

Now i am trying to evaluate the expression

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{6^{n+1}-4} |}{|\frac{(-1)^n}{6^n-4}|} $$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{6^n-4}{6^{n+1}-4} $$

divinding throughout by $6^n$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1-4/6^n}{6-4/6^n} = \frac{1}{6} $$

can anyone verify if $\frac{1}{6}$ is the rate of convergence

Comment: Divide both top and bottom by $6^n$ to compute that final limit

Comment: can i divide throughout by $6^{n+1}$ ? @Mastrem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the final limit you wish to compute, the trick is to divide both top and bottom by $6^n$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{6^n-4}{6^{n+1}-4}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-\frac4{6^n}}{6-\frac4{6^n}}=\frac{1-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac4{6^n}}{6-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac4{6^n}}=\frac16.$$

Comment: yes I did that and got the same value thanks alot for the help can you tell me if this is the correct way to calculate the rate of convergence i came across this formula and started to evaluate the sequence? @Mastrem